# Какой алгоритм использовать для поиска максимального пересечения множества отрезков?

Tags: алгоритм

Есть задача:

В музее регистрируется в течение дня время прихода и ухода каждого посетителя. Таким образом за день получены N пар значений, где первое значение в паре показывает время прихода посетителя и второе значения - время его ухода. Найти промежуток времени, в течение которого в музее одновременно находилось максимальное число посетителей.

Существует ли общеизвестный алгоритм для решения подобных задач?

Comment: Дерево отрезков для суммы подходит для этой задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что существует что-то типовое, но тут оптимальное решение более-менее очевидно.

На базе имеющихся данных сформируйте массив структур:

структура:
время (например, количество секунд с начала суток)
флаг (приход/уход)

O(n) - время формирования такой структуры (линейный проход по интервалам).
Затем отсортируйте эту структуру по времени. В общем случае сложность N*ln(N).

Заведите переменные "начало", "конец", "количество_посетителей" (p1), которые изначально установлены в 0.

Затем по отсортированному массиву двигайтесь от начала к концу, считая количество посетителей в локальную переменную (p2) (приход +1, уход -1, стартовое 0).

Каждый раз, когда p2 меняется, сравнивайте его с p1. Если больше, чем p1, в "начало" установите время текущего элемента массива, в "конец" -1, а в p1 установите p2. Если p2 станет меньше и "конец" = -1, запишите в "конец" время текущего элемента.
Когда пройдете по всему массиву O(n), Вы будете иметь время старта, время конца и количество людей в этот момент.

Сложность алгоритма получается N*ln(N) из-за стандартной сортировки.

Comment: Перевод [этого ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244964/finding-number-of-overlaps-in-a-list-of-time-ranges)? =)

Comment: Не, не гуглил. Тут слишком простая логика) но приятно, когда у меня сходятся мысли с умными людьми)

Comment: @smallFish, спасибо, очень похоже с моим решением на бумаге.

Answer (score 1):

В сообществе олимпиадного программирования, подход для решения подобных задачек, описанный [Arkady](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/364688/397316),  принято называть: сортировка событий + сканирующая прямая (scanline)

В данном случае, событие - приход или уход посетителя в определённое время,
а сканирующая прямая, по мере прохода по событиям, поддерживает текущее количество посетителей и, при необходимости, обновляет/улучшает ответ

Отдельно стоит обратить внимание на порядок сортировки флага (приход/уход посетителя) при равенстве времён и обновление ответа при уходе. Это влияет на тип временного промежутка, будет ли он: отрезком, полуинтервалом или интервалом